# Adding client side calculated fields to django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Say I've got a model like so:

```
class Spam(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
```

On the admin create/edit form. I want to add a non-editable field "c", that will contain the sum of whatever has been entered in a and b.

I have a boatload of ideas on how to accomplish this, and none of them sound very good.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it with [`ModelAdmin.readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

```
class SpamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('get_c',)
    fields = ('a', 'b', 'get_c')

    def get_c(self, obj):
        return obj.a + obj.b
```

Comment: that's not client-side calculated

Comment: In which case, I'm not understanding your problem. It would be three lines of Javascript. Where exactly are you having an issue?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the djangonautical way of adding the javascript is. Would you recommend overriding the admin template for this model to add another field? Should I be specifying a custom form and embedding this in the media?

Comment: You can add a [JS file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions) directly to a ModelAdmin class.