# Display calculated field in template (Django)

Tags: django

Referencing this question:

[Adding client side calculated fields to django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286269/adding-client-side-calculated-fields-to-django-admin)

I would like to do this exactly this such as :

in admin.py:

```
def Calc_result(self, obj):
   a = obj.field1
   b = obj.field2
   return a+b
```

But then display the calculated value in a template as well.

Any ideas on how to go about this? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: So, what problem you're facing here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than that, you could define a property method in your model class:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def calc_result(self):
        return self.field1 + self.field2
```

Then use it in admin site by adding to [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('calc_result',)
```

And use it in template as well:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj.calc_result }}
{% endfor %}
```